# pnpm installs via WSL not usable by Windows

Tags: visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux, pnpm

I had to reinstall Windows after many, many years and after setting everything up again, I've noticed a big difference. Before the reinstallation, I used to run Visual Studio Code from Windows and installed pnpm packages via Bash CLI on WSL - those packages where recognized by Windows VSCode. But if I try this now, Typescript doesn't recognize a single module, resulting in a myriad of errors. Either I run VSCode via WSL remote, or I run pnpm install via Windows. I'm researching for hours, but can't find anything. I've tried WSL 1 and 2.

Furthermore, I've noticed that when I run `pnpm list` on Windows, the same command is being blocked when using it on WSL and vice versa. Access to the node module file directory is then being blocked "on the other side".

I don't remember doing anything special before the reinstallation to set it up like that. What am I missing? Or was it just a weird behavior and sheer luck that it worked like that?